# Actual name or pen-name for bzr whoami?

Tags: bazaar

I am setting up bazaar, and need to tell it my identity using whoami command.

Am confused as to whether I should provide my real name, or my online/pen name for the purpose?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is not necessarily a single correct answer to this question. Bazaar stores the claimed email address in revisions when they're created, so that people can tell who committed which revisions. If you don't plan to publish the branch in a public location, it does not matter at all really. If you do plan to publish the branch or hope to have the changes merged into an existing public project, the identity provided is how you will be attributed. So it is up to you or the policy governing the project you are contributing to whether or not to use your real name.

Also note, that you can set the identity information on a per-branch basis:

```
bzr whoami --branch "Pen Name <nope@example.com>"
```

Answer (score 1):

Which ever you like will do. Maybe you would like the same as your Launchpad account in case you use Launchpad.

Comment: I do use LP, so do you mean the Display Name used there? In that case, are their any legal implications when needed to connect that to my real name?

Comment: @charlie you may want to check [this](http://doc.bazaar.canonical.com/plugins/en/launchpad-plugin.html). I always have set my bazaar account name and mail with the one registered in launchpad tho as the guide says specially since I can submit patches to ubuntu http://packaging.ubuntu.com/html/udd-sponsorship.html#merge-proposal

Comment: Launchpad is a bit of a special case. To push there using the `lp:~username` urls you need to use `lp-login` You should be able to push to `bzr+ssh` urls that you own without that. If you are logged in with `lp-login`, Launchpad will actually show your LP display name rather than the values from `whoami` I tested this here: http://paste.ubuntu.com/6527425/

Comment: @andrewsomething if you read my first phrase say "which ever you like" that is a short version of your own answer, then added the conditionality that if he use LP he might want to use the same ID as Lauchpad ;)

Comment: Launchpad only cares about the email address (for attribution of revisions), not about the display name associated with it.